# How to visualize networks (graphs) with blender?

Tags: python, node-editor, particles

I have a network produced with the python networkX package, and I want to visualize it using Blender. I have done network visualizations before with Gephi, but now I want to visualize a 3d artistic network like the picture below: [image: Refik Anadol's renaissance dreams]

I am a beginner in Blender, and this is my first experience. So what steps should I take to visualize my network produced with Python in Blender and achieve a picture like the above? Is Blender the right choice for the job? Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: The network graph stored in a JASON file contains two JASON objects. One is nodes, and the other is edges. I get this JASON file after visualizing the network in Gephi and export the layout in the JASON format.  In the nodes section, I have the x and y coordinates of each node with the node's id and its attributes like color and size of the node. For example, for node A I have something like this:

{"label":"A","x":279.1,"y":-296.1,"id":"A","attributes":
{"Modularity Class":"1172","Component ID":"1135","Eccentricity":"0.0","Closeness Centrality":"0.0","Betweenness Centrality":"0.0","Harmonic Closeness Centrality":"0.0"},"color":"rgb(192,192,192)","size":10.0}.

The visualization is in 2d, but I think it is also possible to get the 3d network in Gephi so in that case the z coordinate will be available too. In the edges section, I have the start and endpoint of each edge. For example, if node A and B are connected in JASON file I have:

{"source":"A","target":"B","id":"12644","attributes":{},"color":"rgb(192,192,192)","size":1.0}

Comment: i first would recommend to watch some beginner Blender tutorials because the navigation and use of Blender is not intuitive....

Comment: How is the network graph stored? What kind of data do we have here?

Comment: @Chris it is once you got the basics, .

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard: you are right. Don't get me wrong. I love Blender and i learn every day something and Blender surprises me every day even more what it is capable of. But in the beginning i couldn't do anything. I had no idea what icon means what and how to handle it. And i ran against lot's of walls. It's not an iPhone, you use it and it works as you expect. Of course not - because 3D and animation and programming is much more complex and complicated. Maybe there should be something like a playground for beginners in which the functionality is less but more intuitive ;)

Comment: What data format does your network wind up in? A script for this would be quite short.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard, @ Robin Betts: I edited my question and explained the format in which the data is stored.

Comment: Ok, JASON data is nice and easy to read. Hmm, sounds fairly simple, except I’m not sure which part of the data tells how curved inward a connection is. Is it arbitrary?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard It seems that the curvature of the edges is not stored in the JASON file.  Is it possible to give the node coordinates and edge list to Blender and calculate the curvature of the edges by itself? Or maybe randomly assign each edge a curvature? And after that, I edit it by hand to get the desired shape I want?

Comment: Probably. I might use free curve handles, and make them all point towards the center of the mass, but only stretch about halfway to it. That might give you the kind of curvature you want.